# How best to access current_user devise helper in backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, devise

I'm new to backbone and rails and building my first app.  I want to be able to populate an array in my contact model with the current user id.  I am using rails and devise which supplies the current_user helper.

I have created a currentuser method in my user controller as follows:

```
 class UserController < ApplicationController  
  def currentuser
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

I have set up a backbone model called currentuser and set up the correct url

```
class ContactManager.Models.Currentuser extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  idAttribute: '_id'
  urlRoot: -> '/user/currentuser/'
```

And in my backbone view I am trying to set a variable which contains the current user id as follows.

```
currentuser = new ContactManager.Models.Currentuser()
currentuser.fetch()
console.log(currentuser)
id = currentuser.get('id')
console.log(currentuser.id)
this.model.get('favorite_ids').push(id)
console.log(this.model.get('favorite_ids'))
this.model.save()
```

This seems to work in the console but in my application id is undefined.  What am I doing wrong here or is there a better way of doing it.  This method was suggesed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582716/retrieve-rails-devise-current-user-from-backbone) but not elaborate upon.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: The `currentuser.fetch()` call will be asynchronous. Try adding a `success` handler to it (see http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch). Also check if your `UserController#currentuser` method is getting called.

Comment: thanks!! yes I needed to add the success callback and then grab the id I needed out of the response._id attribute and then pushed in onto the end of my array.  Been struggling for hours you're a total lifesaver.

Comment: Interesting way of fetching the current user... is the `idAttribute` set to `_id` because you're using Mongoid, or is it a slightly hacky way of making sure that calling fetch twice doesn't raise a 404? If not - is there an elegant solution for doing this via backbone?

Comment: the _id is because I am using mongoid.  I am using rails so I now use the gon gem to populate the current_user as a javascript variable and set a current_user model in backbone on initialisation.  Then I use sockets to keep the current_user in sync.